# How to wait until user close the frame to be able to run the rest of the code?

Tags: java, frame, wait

I have this code here, it's a button that call another jFrame to edit stuff, the stuff goes into a jTable that need user input to update. I want to make this update automatic, by puting in the same button, but nothing hapens when I call the function that update the jTable, problably because the java machine don't wait...

```
private void editarImovelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) // Button {                                             
    int i = 0;
    int linha = tabelaImoveis.getSelectedRow(); // tabelaImoveis = jTable
    if (tabelaImoveis.isRowSelected(linha)) {
        {
            try { 
                Integer codigo = Integer.parseInt(tabelaImoveis.getValueAt(linha, 0).toString());
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                mensagem.message("Linha sem Valor!"); 
                i = 1;
            } finally {
                if (i == 0) { 
                    Integer codigo = Integer.parseInt(tabelaImoveis.getValueAt(linha, 0).toString());
                    for (Imovel imovel : imovelLista) { 

                        if (imovel.getCodigo() == codigo) {                               frmAlterar alterar = new frmAlterar();
                            alterar.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                            alterar.setVisible(true);
                            alterar.setDefaultCloseOperation(alterar.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                            alterar.setarAtributos(imovel);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        mensagem.message("Select Something!"); // Same as System.out...
    }


    updatejTable(); // This code here I want to execute after the frame "alterar" closes
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this is the same as for all similar questions (and there are many): don't use another JFrame, use a modal JDialog.

```
    if (i == 0) { 
        Integer codigo = Integer.parseInt(tabelaImoveis.getValueAt(linha, 0).toString());
        for (Imovel imovel : imovelLista) { 
            if (imovel.getCodigo() == codigo) {                               
                frmAlterar alterar = new frmAlterar();  // *** this should be a modal JDialog
                alterar.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                // alterar.setVisible(true);
                // alterar.setDefaultCloseOperation(alterar.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                alterar.setarAtributos(imovel);
                alterar.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Skip over to [`How to make Dialogs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for some more info